# Environment allowing Fortran to call a C function

Tags: c, fortran

I'm trying to install a large atmospheric model (WRF) on my newly set up Centos 7 machine.

To start the installation process, the model's developers give a series of environmental tests.  My set up fails the fourth one--Fortran Calling a C Function.  (I passed the first three: fixed and free format Fortran and C only.)

This test consists of two small programs.

First, TEST_4_fortran+c_c.c:

```
::::::::::::::
TEST_4_fortran+c_c.c
::::::::::::::
#ifndef CRAY
# ifdef NOUNDERSCORE
#      define C_TEST c_test
# else
#   ifdef F2CSTYLE
#      define C_TEST c_test__
#   else
#      define C_TEST c_test_
#   endif
# endif
#endif
#include <stdio.h>

int C_TEST ( float *xx, int *ii )

{
 printf("   C function called by Fortran\n" ) ;
 printf("   Values are xx = %5.2f and ii = %d \n", *xx, *ii ) ;
 return(0) ;
}
```

Compiling it "gcc -c -m64 TEST_4_fortran+c_c.c" went fine with no errors.

The second program,  TEST_4_fortran+c_f.f90:

```
PROGRAM foo
   INTEGER :: ii
   REAL    :: xx

   ii = 1
   xx = 2

   CALL c_test ( xx , ii )

   print *,'SUCCESS test 4 fortran calling c'

END PROGRAM foo
```

Compiling `gfortran -c -m64 TEST_4_fortran+c_f.f90` also had no errors.

When I attempt to execute the fortran `gfortran -m64 TEST_4_fortran+c_f.o` I get:

```
TEST_4_fortran+c_f.o: In function `MAIN__':
TEST_4_fortran+c_f.f90:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `c_test_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I just installed Centos 7, so everything is "out of the box."

Comment: Without testing myself, does the case matter? You've defined `C_TEST` but called `c_test`...

Comment: Case should not matter, should be handled by `#if` etc, in the C program

Comment: When linking you use `gfortran -m64 TEST_4_fortran+c_f.o` where is the reference to `TEST_4_fortran+c_c..o` ? There might be more issues like missing libraries, but this one is the first that I see.

Comment: Yes, the C object file is never linked with the executable.

Comment: yes, link it with `gfortran -m64 TEST_4_fortran+c_f.o TEST_4_fortran+c_c.o -o TEST_4_fortran+c_f` and run it with `./TEST_4_fortran+c_f`

Comment: I wonder why they didn't ship the tests suite with an easy to run script or makefile.

Comment: Thank you mosvy!  That did it.